# Java pass generator with special requirements

Tags: java, arrays

I just need a password generator with special requirements.
I did this code. It works very well but how to take from this String-only 2 special character;-only 2 digits;-only 3 characters in lowercase;-only 3 characters in uppercase.

```
  private static void passGenerator(){
            int length = 8;
            String symbol = "-/.^&*_!@%=+>)";
            String cap_letter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            String small_letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            String numbers = "0123456789";
            String finalString = cap_letter + small_letter +
                    numbers + symbol;
            Random random = new Random();
            char[] password = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                password[i] = finalString.charAt(random.nextInt(finalString.length()));

            }
            System.out.println(password);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library by [apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). There are some useful methods for split string to array by characters with different cases, by different characters at all (a3 will be a, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I would first generate the password in a specific order and store it in a temporary variable, say like this:

```
{ special1, special2, digit1, digit2, lower1, lower2, lower3, upper1, upper2, upper3}
```

This would likely need to be hard coded.

Next, I would create a new password variable, and one by one choose a character and add it to the new variable.  Do this by randomly generating a number [0, temp.length).  Then, copy the char at that index to the lowest unfilled spot in the new password, remove it from the temp, and copy all the remaining chars to a new temp array one element smaller.  Repeat until the temp array size is zero.